# Is there way of distinguishing between characters and numbers?

Tags: bash

I've got a BASH script, which constantly interprets incoming datum. I was hoping if there is a way of BASH to realizing whether it's a combination of letters for example `hi`, `bye bye` or numbers `123451`.

What would be the snippet of code look like??

```
awk_variables=`echo "$line" | awk -F, '{print $1, $4, $5, $7, $10 }'`
awk_variables_value_array=($awk_variables)          #turns contents of 'awk_variables' into an array 'awk_variables_value_array'
```

^ This is the part of the code which does the reading from a `($)line` from a csv file. It's here the datum could be 'hello' or numbers if thats the case I don't want to read it. However `$4` does have letters when it gets read.

**Q:** What would the script look like if it were to be *able* to distinguish the datum from letters and numbers?

---

**Ideally:**
An alternative approach could be if a bit of code could count how many parameters there are in a given `($)line`. If the parameters are not equal to an *x* amount, I could not read it, and skip to the next line. **Q:** What would the script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a line (here, `$line`) into an array (here, `${array[@]}`) using `,` as a delimiter:

```
IFS=, read -r -a array <<<"$line"
```

To see how many values were put into the array:

```
${#array[@]}
```

To see if a specific element consists only of numbers:

```
! [[ ${array[4]} =~ [^0-9] ]]
```

(The `!` could also go inside the `[[...]]`. Adjust the character class if you want to include negative numbers, decimal points, etc.)

Comment: Can I substitute `array` with `awk_variables_value_array`? And also would this work `number_of_values_in_array=${#array[@]}` ie assign a variable to  `${#array[@]}`

Comment: @3kstc: It's just a name. You could put `the_sky_is_blue_but_its_raining` if you wanted to. Or `r`. Up to you. The important bit is the `-a` flag, which means "put the split pieces into the array with the following name".

Comment: last question: `number_of_values_in_array=${#array[@]} ` this would also work?

Comment: Only if you call the array `array`. `${#array[@]}` is "just" a parameter expansion, no different from "${array[4]}", except that it is replaced with the length of the named array variable instead of the value of an element. With scalars, `${#foo}` is the length of `$foo` (in characters), and `${#array[4]}` would be the length in characters of the indicated element.

Comment: In addition to defining the contents of the character class manually, bash also provides predefined character classes you can use within brackets. Using `[^:digit:]` is equivalent to `[^0-9]` above. The syntax for predefined class use is `[:classname:]` where the classname can be one of `alnum alpha ascii blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper word xdigit`